# uiview getter nil

Tags: iphone, uiview, uiviewcontroller, drawrect, getter

I am trying to get certain iVars from my view controller to my view (a subview) so drawrect will draw a shape based on user inputs.  When I hard code those variables into the subview, the shape draws perfect, but when I use getters to access the custom variables from the view controller, they come back nil and the drawing is messed up.  I get no errors or warnings.  I know there is a problem with the getter, any suggestions?  Anybody have an example of passing variables to a subview so cgcontext can be used in the drawrect?  I am stuck big time.  I assume at this point my problem is so simple, I am missing something fundamental.  I thought I had setters/getters down packed.

Comment: It would be way easier to help you if you posted the code in question.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that whatever you're getting 'from' (ie, the parent, or view, or whatever you're accessing the getters on) is not nil. Try setting a break point right before accessing them and validating that your targets are valid, and have valid data.

Comment: I know the ivars on the controller are not nil because they are used to set a label on said controller.  Those labels are correct.

Comment: can you call the getters from the debugger? Are these properties or standard getter methods?

Comment: can you step into them in the debugger?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean "step in".

Comment: using the debugger, can you break just before your getter gets called, and step into the code to see what's happening.

Comment: I see, yes, I can use a breakpoint and step in now.  Thanks for the help there.  The iVars being got have the appropriate values at the breakpoint.

Comment: at this point, I think we're pretty much stuck without some code snippets.

Comment: Does the view have to be a subclass of the viewcontroller?  I can make it so, but it'll be a little work.

Comment: a view cannot be a subclass of UIViewController.

Comment: Yeah, I found that out the hard way.  Anyway thanks for the help.  I'm gonna keep searching.  The getter just doesn't get.

Answer (score 0):

We'd really need to see more code. Ben was saying that, somewhere in your view, you must set `parent = (some code to get a reference to my parent)`. Make sure this actually works, i.e. you really do have a reference to your parent. Even if the ivars are correct, if your parent is nil, then sending `[nil getSomeiVar]` will return 0 in most cases.

Without a better understanding of the code, this is my guess. Somewhere in your UIViewController, you should have something like:

```
myView = //make your view
[myView setParent:self]
```

Parent is a variable of the view, with a property so that you can access it

Edit:
Why does it matter if we know what you are making?

For setParent to work, you need to following:

1. an ivar `YourUIViewControllerSubclass *parent;` in your view's .h
2. a property for this ivar `@property (nonatomic, retain) YourUIViewControllerSubclass *parent;` in your view's .h
3. A synthesis for this ivar `@synthesize parent;` in your view's .m inside the `@implementation`

Comment: My app is too simple to post code.  It'll be a dead give away what I am making.

Comment: It says the view does not respond to setParent.  The viewcontroller doesn't either.

Comment: Did this help you any or can you give us some more info to try to figure it out?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you were both wrong, but I took a lot away from you helping me though.  I didn't have to post code after all.  I had to pick up my debugging skills big time.  Someone in another post mentioned violations of the MVC.  I had to set the ivars in the uiview, to the custom values FROM the view CONTROLLER.  In other words, I had to set from the controller rather than getting from the subview.